# Adding MenuItem to the allready existing WPF header Menu

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, menuitem, application-icon

[What at the moment is, What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAtok.png)

I want to add an MenuItem to the existing Menu that opens when you click on the Application Icon.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using interops to go to Win32 calls... First override the SourceInitialized method for the Window and add the following:

```
public const uint MyMenuItemID = 0x0555;

private const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
private const uint MF_BYPOSITION = 0x00000400;

[DllImport ("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu (IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport ("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool InsertMenu (IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags, uint uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

private void Window_SourceInitialized (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual (this) as HwndSource;
    if (source != null) {
        IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu (source.Handle, false);
        InsertMenu (hMenu, 5, MF_BYPOSITION, MyMenuItemID, "my own MenuItem");
    }
}
```